# Laravel3 migration on production server error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, migration, laravel, database-migration, production-environment

I tried my database migration in fortrabbit.com through SSH, but I got an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

How to specify database name, password of  production database?

How to do Laravel3 migration via SSH access in production server. I have used pagodabox it was working fine but very costly, so I switched to fortrabbit.com.

I tried this http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=6177, but no solution.

Comment: Are you using foreign keys than seeding? Maybe some value in seeding are missing. The DB don't accept missing value in foreign key relations.

Answer (score 1):

We surely will need more info about your problem.

To do a migration on Laravel using ssh, you basically have to go to your app folder and execute `php artisan migrate`. But I think you know that, right?

To specify your database infor for production,

1.create a ditectory production inside your app/config

2.copy your current app/config/database.php to it

3.edit your new app/config/production/database.php

4.on your app/start/global.php, configure your environment:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'development'    => array('localhost'),
    'production'     => array('example.com')
));
```

But to clarify it even better, you can watch this fresh video from Jeffrey Way on Laracasts:

https://laracasts.com/lessons/from-zero-to-deploy-with-fortrabbit